# mkdir: cannot create directory permission denied when launching hadoop

Tags: command-line, software-installation, permissions, hadoop

I get this error whenever I try to launch Hadoop. I have already configured the files needed to launch it but I get:

```
$ hdfs namenode -format

WARNING: /home/jeunesseafricaine/hadoop-3.3.1/logs does not exist. Creating.
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/home/jeunesseafricaine/hadoop-3.3.1/logs’: Permission denied
ERROR: Unable to create /home/jeunesseafricaine/hadoop-3.3.1/logs. Aborting.
```

Need some help.

Answer (score 0):

if this directory exists try to remove it by:

```bash
$ sudo rm -rf /home/jeunesseafricaine/hadoop-3.3.1
```

then recreating this directory without `sudo`

```bash
$ mkdir -p /home/jeunesseafricaine/hadoop-3.3.1/logs
```

- it makes this directory use your own permission

## Another Help

```bash
$ sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /home/jeunesseafricaine/hadoop-3.3.1
$ sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /home/jeunesseafricaine/hadoop-3.3.1/logs
```